# ViewPagerIndicator Tabs: Icons above Text

Tags: android, icons, viewpagerindicator

I'm using the [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)
and I would like to change the tab style so I could get icons above text, instead of the default, which places the icon on the left side, and the title to the right.

Comment: Hi, Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 13):

The reason why the icons always appear on the left is because of this piece of code:

```
if (iconResId != 0) {
     tabView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iconResId, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

found in [`TabPageIndicator.java`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/TabPageIndicator.java)

This is part of a private method (`addTab()`), and so, cannot be changed without modifying the library itself.

Luckily, this isn't too hard to do. Make sure that you have the `ViewPagerIndicator` source code downloaded, then open up `TabPageIndicator.java`

If you want to change the location permanently (as permanent as you can get with a source code change), change the location of `iconResId` in the [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method. For example, placing the icons at the top needs `iconResId` to be the second argument to the method.

```
tabView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, iconResId, 0, 0);
```

If you need something a little more flexible, I came up with these changes (still in `TabPageIndicator.java`) that should work. These changes have been mirrored [on my GitHub](https://github.com/andreiciubotariu/Android-ViewPagerIndicator), so there is a working example.

Member variables:

```
/**
* Constants to improve readability - no magic numbers.
*/
public final static int LOCATION_LEFT =0;
public final static int LOCATION_UP = 1;
public final static int LOCATION_RIGHT = 2;
public final static int LOCATION_BOTTOM =3;

/**
* Stores the location of the tab icon
*/
private int location = LOCATION_LEFT;

/**
* Used to store the icon.
*/
private int [] drawables = new int [4];

/**
 * Holds the value used by setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds used to denote no icon.
 */
private static int NO_ICON = 0;
```

Add this method:

```
public void setTabIconLocation (int newLocation){
    if (location > LOCATION_BOTTOM || location < LOCATION_LEFT)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Invalid location");
    this.location = newLocation;
    for (int x = 0; x < drawables.length;x++){
        drawables [x] = NO_ICON;
    }
}
```

In `addTab()`, change

```
if (iconResId != 0) {
     tabView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iconResId, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

to

```
if (iconResId != 0) {
    drawables [location] = iconResId;
    tabView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawables[0], drawables[1], drawables[2], drawables[3]);
}
```

Non-library implementation (taken from the sample code provided)

```
TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
indicator.setTabIconLocation (TabPageIndicator.LOCATION_UP);
indicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the working copy on Github, much appreciated! I was afraid of it not being possible through the library itself. Ah well, perhaps I'll sens a pull request (unless you're going to do it :)). Again, thanks.

Comment: I just realized I cannot assign bounty points yet (can only do that after 24 hrs): I will divide them between you and Robert when I am able to.

Comment: @BartKiers No problem :-) I made some small changes to the code, and once I verify that it is working, properly, I'll send a pull request.

Comment: nice, I saw the pull request: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/pull/232 Note that I saw you made the pull against the `master` branch, which should probably be the `dev` branch instead.

Comment: @BartKiers seems everyone's pull requests are against master, so I think I'll keep the pull request as it is :-)

Comment: ah, didn't look at that. I seem to remember Jake Wharton asking someone to make the pull against `dev`, but that must have been another repo then.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this effect by modifying only 1 line in the source code of ViewPageIndicator library.

The line to be modified is in the number `180` in the `TabPageIndicator` class inside the `addTab` method ( at least on today's version of the code 28/05/2013 )

The original file is

```
180        tabView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( iconResId, 0, 0, 0 );
```

And you should modify it to the following if you want the icon to go on top of text.

```
180        tabView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0, iconResId, 0, 0 );
```

Here's an screenshot of the change

[image]

As you probably guessed by now, you can put the icon anywhere around the text by playing with the iconResId within the different arguments of the `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` method.

Comment: Robert, I just awarded all points to A--C. I thought I could split the point over multiple answers, but apparently not the way I created the bounty. Sorry! Your answer *is* appreciated, nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

There is a cleaner way to do that without modifying the library. Just copy and paste the class [TabPageIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/TabPageIndicator.java) to your project and modify the lines pointed out in the other answers. Then rename the class to whatever you like and use it as if it was a `TabPageIndicator`.