# Centering icon on TabPageIndicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I normally google and research things before asking questions, but this time I failed to find answer in a normal way, so I had to seek your assistance, fellow programmers.

I'm using [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator), TabPageIndicator class in particular and want to achieve following without modification of library: removing test labels from tabs and horizontally centering icon. While first part is quite trivial (just return `null` from `getPageTitle()`), the second one left me baffled, as I'm unable to find presumably obvious way to position icons in the center apart from use of `margin` parameter, which is totally wrong and unacceptable, as you can imagine.

The most obvious, setting `gravity` in `vpi_styles.xml`, did not work:

```
<style name="Widget.TabPageIndicator" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/vpi__tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">22dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">22dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.TabPageIndicator</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:width">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">40dp</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.IconPageIndicator" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal|center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the ViewPagerIndicator Lib, and add support for IconsOnly tabs
https://github.com/JafarKhQ/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: You should explicitly credit Jake Wharton then, not just by copying his README.MD file.

Comment: Uh. Name is in quite small and different font, haven't reacted on it as a part of text. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it seems like I haven't searched thoroughly enough: I used second answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735278/viewpagerindicator-tabs-icons-above-text?rq=1) and received needed effect by modifying `TabPageIndicator.java` file:

Changed

```
tabView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iconResId, 0, 0, 0);
```

to

```
tabView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, iconResId, 0, 0);
```

and my icon got centered.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done was create a copy of TabPageIndicator and make the necessary changes to represent only Icons and center in the cell.

To use this just copy IconCenterPageIndicator.java  from this gist

https://gist.github.com/pedrolaranjeiro/2a0aac0723e44e54c621

to com.viewpagerindicator and follow the XML and the adapter examples to achieve what you are looking for.